# Styling a LongListSelector in Windows Phone apps

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-8

How do I style a LongListSelector to look like below?

[image]

I have tried styling it as you would normally style a ListView in a XAML (Windows Store) app or Desktop app but obviously it's different so it didn't work. I have also spent a while searching but I have never seen anything like this for a LongListSelector. But there are no other types of lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it.

You need to add `LayoutMode="Grid"` and `GridCellSize="75, 75"`:

`<phone:LongListSelector LayoutMode="Grid" GridCellSize="170, 150"/>`

Answer (score 0):

i think u are looking for `WrapPanel`
more info at http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/wp7-wrappanel-in-depth